# replace specific condition with a variable

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, simplify

http://jsfiddle.net/LPCpR/

```
<select id="menu1">
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
</select>
<select id="menu2">
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
    <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
</select>
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is('#menu1')) {
        alert('menu hone has been changed')
    }
})
```

The above illustrates two menus and a condition: if menu one is selected, alert. There are actually five menus in my code, so I need to streamline.

Need to replace the condition with a line which assigns a variable to the id of the changed menu. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    switch(id)
    {
        case "menu1":
            alert('menu 1 changed');
            break;
        case "menu2":
            alert('menu 2 changed');
            break;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPCpR/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to apply this to the fieldset? I realise that each of the select fields may need to be in a separate fieldset. The simplest way from here would be to ignore fieldsets but it would be less developing :)
How to alert the id of the fieldset?
http://jsfiddle.net/qYmZa/

Comment: You can use `closest()` on http://api.jquesry.com/closest like `$(this).closest('fieldset').attr('id');` in the `onchange` function.

Comment: it is suggested below on this page that onclick is not advisable. can you think of a method similar to the one you proposed initially, but for fieldset? I have tried this:
http://jsfiddle.net/LPCpR/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 <select id="menu1" onchange="changeEvent(this);">
   <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
   <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
   <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
   <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
 </select>
 <select id="menu2" onchange="changeEvent(this);">
  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
 function changeEvent(obj)
 {
    alert(obj.id);
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPCpR/2/)

Comment: i wouldnt recommend using `onchange`. Its old and clunky. and degrades performance and maintainability

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the id by using id attribute...Try the below solution to check which menu is changed.

```
  $('select').change(function () {
        if ($(this)) {
            alert( 'menu' + this.id + 'has been changed')
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('select').change(function () {

        alert(  $(this).attr('id') + 'has been changed')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LPCpR/12/


<select id="menu_one">
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
</select>
<select id="menu_two">
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top">- SELECT -</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="bottom" selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">Trees</option>
<option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right">Bushes</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
 $('select').change(function () {

      var menuNo = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
      alert('menu '+menuNo[1]+' has been changed');

   });
```

you can see the js fiddle for the solution.